# Ambiguous use of an overloaded function

Tags: swift

I have a bunch of overloaded functions:

```swift
func foo() {
  print("foo")
}

func foo(i: Int = 0) {
  print("foo with i")
}

func foo(_ s: String = "") {
  print("foo with s")
}
```

If I want to call each of them with default parameter values I can do the following:

```swift
foo() // foo
foo(i:)() // foo with i
foo(_:)() // foo with s
```

But it doesn't work when I have two functions with unlabelled first arguments:

```swift
func foo(_ s: String = "") {
  print("foo with s")
}

func foo(_ f: Float = 0) {
  print("foo with f")
}

foo(_:)() // Ambiguous use of 'foo'
```

Is it possible to tell the swift compiler which one I want to call?

Comment: If you don't have control over the original functions then you could call them through wrapper functions, such as: `func stringFoo(_ s: String = "") { foo(s) }`. If you do have control over the functions then of course you can rename them and make life a bit easier.

Answer (score 2):

There are no solution for this situation.

Problem is compiler doesn't know which function to use when you call func with default input parameter:

```
func foo(_ s: String = "") {
  print("foo with s")
}

func foo(_ f: Float = 0) {
  print("foo with f")
}

foo() // Ambiguous use of 'foo'
```

Both of those functions are have default value and possibly can be called `foo()` and compiler doesn't know which one you need to call.

All you can do is to remove default input parameter for at least one of those functions.

```
func foo(_ s: String) { // removed default value here
  print("foo with s")
}

func foo(_ f: Float = 0) {
  print("foo with f")
}

foo() // will call `foo(0.0)`
```

Or you can rename one of those functions and you will be able to set  default input parameters to both of them.

```
func foo(_ s: String = "") {
  print("foo with s")
}

func fooF(_ f: Float = 0) { // renamed here
  print("foo with f")
}

fooF() // will call `fooF(0.0)`
foo() // will call `foo("")`
```

Comment: Yes, I can change signatures of the functions to resolve the issue, but I am interested in the described case.

Comment: @iUrii But as the first sentence of the answer tells you, there is no solution: the compiler has no basis for picking one or the other, and it rightly tells you so. What question do you have left?

Comment: You could distinguish by assigning it like `let f: (String) -> Void = foo` but that won't help with default parameters.